# How does RSpec reload work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I don't understand why the first of the following test passes while the second does not. Obviously, it's because I'm using a block in the first one, but what does it actually do compared to the second scenario?

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Edit user account" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before(:each) do
    sign_in_as!(user)
    visit '/settings'
  end

  scenario 'A user should be able to update their login info with current password' do
    fill_in 'user_first_name', :with => 'Mario'
    fill_in 'user_email', :with => 'mario@bross.com'
    fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'goshrooms'
    fill_in 'user_current_password', :with => 'ilovebananas'
    click_button 'Update'

    user.reload do |u|
      u.first_name.should eq 'Mario'
      u.email.should eq 'mario@bross.com'
      u.password.should eq 'goshrooms'
    end
    current_path.should eq '/settings'
    page.should have_content('You updated your account successfully.')
  end

  scenario "A user should be able to update their login info with current password" do
    fill_in "user_password", :with => "magical"
    fill_in "user_current_password", :with => 'ilovebananas'
    click_button "Update"

    current_path.should eq "/settings"
    user.reload.password.should eq "magical"
  end
end
```

When running the tests I get:

```
1) Edit user account A user should be able to update their login info with current password
 Failure/Error: user.reload.password.should eq "magical"

   expected: "magical"
        got: "ilovebananas"

   (compared using ==)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `reload` method actually takes a block? Seems to me like your assertions in the first scenario are never executed.

Comment: @JiříPospíšil, you were right: reload doesn't take a block and my tests were not executed.

Comment: @Tass, you're right too. Password is not a DB field, just an attribute on user. I ended up testing the encrypted_password field instead (see answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, password is not a field in the DB. So instead of testing on password, I tested on the encrypted_password field.

```
 feature "* Edit user account:" do
   let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }  

   before(:each) do
      visit "/login"
      fill_in "user_email", :with => user.email
      fill_in "user_password", :with => "ilovebananas"
      click_button "Sign in"
      visit '/settings'
      @old_encrypted_password = user.encrypted_password
    end

    scenario 'A user should be able to update their info with current password' do
      ....
      user.reload.encrypted_password.should_not eq @old_encrypted_password
    end
end
```

Comment: How would you do that then? Add another login/authentication test at the end?